# Write more efficiently in Java

Tags: java, arrays, datetime, date-format, epoch

can you guys help me to displaying the time difference in Java. I've done it but there's some code that should not have to be rewritten.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Time {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Date dt = new Date();
        DateFormat[] dtformat = new DateFormat[6];
        dtformat[0] = DateFormat.getInstance();
        dtformat[1] = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        dtformat[2] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        dtformat[3] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
        dtformat[4] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
        dtformat[5] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        System.out.println("Today :");
        for(DateFormat dateform : dtformat)
            System.out.println(dateform.format(dt));

        String str = "May 21 1980";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
        Date date = df.parse(str);
        long epoch = date.getTime();

        Date dl = new Date(epoch);
        DateFormat[] dlformat = new DateFormat[6];
        dlformat[0] = DateFormat.getInstance();
        dlformat[1] = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        dlformat[2] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        dlformat[3] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
        dlformat[4] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
        dlformat[5] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
            System.out.println("\nDate of Birth :");
            for(DateFormat dateform : dlformat)
            System.out.println(dateform.format(dl));

            System.out.println("\nDifference Days: " + Diff(dl,dt) + " hari");
    }
    public static long Diff(Date dl, Date dt) {
        long diffdays = dt.getTime() - dl.getTime();
        long days = diffdays / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        return days;
    }
}
```

The output should be the same, like :
9/24/17 11:31 PM

Sep 24, 2017

Sep 24, 2017

Sunday, September 24, 2017

September 24, 2017

9/24/17

Comment: If this code works, ask your question at [codereview.se].

Comment: @AndyTurner Why can't we select CR as an alternative site where this question should be posted when flagging this question?

Comment: As an aside, is there any particular reason why you are still struggling with the long outdated classes `Date` and not least the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`? I recommend you throw them out and use the modern `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()`. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will pretty much does as your code, but removes the repeated section of the logic by moving it to a separated method.Everytime you need to print any date with the specified Date Formats,You can call `printDates` by passing a `Date` Object

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Time {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Date dt = new Date();
        printDates(dt);

        String str = "May 21 1980";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
        Date date = df.parse(str);
        long epoch = date.getTime();

        Date dl = new Date(epoch);
        printDates(dl);

            System.out.println("\nDifference Days: " + Diff(dl,dt) + " hari");
    }
    public static long Diff(Date dl, Date dt) {
        long diffdays = dt.getTime() - dl.getTime();
        long days = diffdays / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        return days;
    }


    public static void printDates(Date date){
          DateFormat[] dlformat = new DateFormat[6];
          dlformat[0] = DateFormat.getInstance();
          dlformat[1] = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
          dlformat[2] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
          dlformat[3] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
          dlformat[4] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
          dlformat[5] = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
          System.out.println("\nDate of Birth :");
          for(DateFormat dateform : dlformat)
          System.out.println(dateform.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, sir :)